# SQL Server 2008: why do I see only system tables when I login ODBC from ACCESS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, ssms

I am using Access to try to get some links to tables in SQL Server 2008.

I've created a user name under security in SSMS for SQL Server and I've mapped it to a user that is under the database that I need. I've also given that user a default database that I need.

When I try to connect through ODBC I am not seeing the correct tables. What I am seeing is a bunch of `Sys` tables. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Here is the create for the main user:

```
/* For security reasons the login is created disabled and with a random password. */
/****** Object:  Login [lomuser]    Script Date: 10/22/2010 08:14:03 ******/
CREATE LOGIN [lomuser] WITH PASSWORD=N'µ''ØÑëOº\¾dõMÐàæfÄ%[RríÜ2 y', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[LOMDATABASE], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

ALTER LOGIN [lomuser] DISABLE
GO
```

Here is the create for the specific user to the specific database (on which the top user is mapped to) also FYI they have the same name:

```
USE [LOMDATABASE]
GO

CREATE USER [lomuser] FOR LOGIN [lomuser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

Comment: if you *only* see the sys catalog views, it's most likely a permission issue - the user you're using to connect doesn't have any rights to see tables...

Comment: @marc_s how do i assign permissions?

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx

Comment: @marc_s im sorry can you please help more, i have the same set up on a different database and everything works fine, it's just this one is a problkem

Comment: If there are 2 databases - one works and the other doesn't, then they're not the same.  The problem lies in the differences between the 2.

Comment: Can you change from ODBC to OleDB ?? Much easier and much more reliable, in my opinion. Does that change anything??

Comment: @marc_s it's a good point but access only supports odbc i believe

Comment: Also: if you connect to that SQL Server database using SSMS and that user account - do you see the tables you're interested in??

Comment: @marc_s GREAT POINT!!!!!!! i am able to connect, however i do not see the tables that i need!

Comment: @marc_s what am i doing wrong? how do i grant the permission for the table?

Comment: Access has supported native oleDB connections to sql server for 10 years. Access developers don't use nor recommend oleDB (urban legend stuff for the un-informed). Access odbc and using DAO is far better. This also applies for support of SharePoint and new Access features of disconnected tables that sync up into cloud with SharePoint  (and Access Web services will also be part of Office 365 again uses DAO).Same goes for Azure (Support is baked into access and again via ODBC). The oleDB support for Azure and access is not in place and we likely not see anything in this regards for Azure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you setup the DSN connection in the odbc panel or let access create this connection for you, the default database is master. So, when you link a table, the only tables you will see are the system tables. Delete your linked table (if you have any). Now, when you choose to link to a table, choose NEW in the data source to create a new DSN connection. During that process, you see the option to change the default database from system to whatever database you want.

[image]

Once you change the above default, then when you link a table, you see tables from the above selected database you choose. If you did not set above, as noted, you just going to see the system tables.

Answer (score 5):

You may find a solution in [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2513216) at Microsoft support

This is a known bug in SQL Server 
Beware of denying Select to the Public 
because it has unintended results elsewhere

The solutions can be difficult for a casual SQL administrator.

Comment: the link is not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

By default when setting up (importing) a linked table from an (Azure) SQL Server database MS ACCESS chooses `master` as the default database. You should change this when linking the table:

**1**-Click `Linked Table Manager` under `External Data` tab

[image]

**2**-Click `Add` button on the right menu bar and choose `SQL (Server/Azure)`, enter a name for the data source (so you can recognize the data source later in the Link Table Manager list of sources), click `Next`

[image]

**3**-When SQL Server Login wizard prompted, enter the address of your SQL server e.g. for Azure it should be something like this:

<you_server_name>.database.windows.net

Enter your SQL database user and password for login.

Once done, the button `Options` will be enabled

**4**-Click button `Options` and you will see the Database is set to `Default`. Click on it and choose the database you want. You should see the tables of the selected database and not `master`

[image]